# Analytical solution to first order nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics

Can we find analytical solution for this ODE?

$$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2+y^2=\frac{a}{(bx-x^3)^2}$$

Where $ a, b $ are real constants.